# How do Boost.Geometry operations like union_ deal with the fundamental imprecision of floating point types?

Tags: c++, boost-geometry

I'm trying to judge whether / how I can make Boost.Geometry work for a particular use case. I cannot, however, find documentation about how the library deals with floating point types anywhere.

If you search the official documentation for the word "epsilon" you get zero hits as far as I can tell; however, it is clear from the library's behavior that it is implicitly using some version of the typical way one deals with floats when making comparisons because, for example, the union_ operation will union two polygons that are near each other but not overlapping if they are near enough.

Consider for example the following code which performs a binary search to determine the threshold distance that two unit squares need to be within to be considered adjacent when union-ing:

```c++
namespace bg = boost::geometry;

using point = bg::model::d2::point_xy<double>;
using polygon = bg::model::polygon<point, false>;

polygon create_poly(std::vector<std::tuple<double, double>> pts) {
    polygon poly;
    for (const auto& [x, y] : pts)
        bg::append(poly, bg::make<point>(x, y));
    auto [x_1, y_1] = pts[0];
    bg::append(poly, bg::make<point>(x_1, y_1));
    return poly;
}

bool perform_simple_union(const polygon& p1, const polygon& p2) {
    std::vector<polygon> output; 
    bg::union_(p1, p2, output);
    return output.size() == 1;
}

double find_epsilon(double left, double right) {

    if (right - left < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())
        return left;
    double eps = (left + right) / 2;

    polygon a = create_poly(
        std::vector<std::tuple<double, double>>{
            {1.0, 1.0}, { 2.0,1.0 }, { 2.0, 2.0 }, { 1.0,2.0 }
        }
    );

    polygon b = create_poly(
        std::vector<std::tuple<double, double>>{
            {2.0 + eps, 1.0}, { 3.0 + eps, 1.0 }, { 3.0 + eps, 2.0 }, { 2.0 + eps,2.0 }
        }
    );

    if ( perform_simple_union(a, b) ) {
        return find_epsilon(eps, right);
    } else {
        return find_epsilon(left, eps);
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto eps = find_epsilon(0.0, 1.0);
    std::cout << "eps == " << eps << "\n";
}
```

when I compile and run the above with Visual Studio I get the output

> eps == 1e-07

which is about the numeric limits epsilon of single precision floats. So it's treating double precision coordinates as if they are equivalent if they are within single precision epsilon from each other?

Basically I'd just like to know what the default behavior is so I can decide if it works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the intro][1], it states:

> The library supports high precision arithmetic numbers, such as ttmath.
> [1]: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/introduction.html

The library [design rationale](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/design.html) goes into this a tiny bit more:

> [...], it would be too long, and it is not related to geometry. We just assume that there is a meta-function select_most_precise selecting the best type.

They also implemented along the OGC Simple Feature Specification, which probably means that you can find [more algorithmic robustness guarantees there](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfa).

I know from reading the code that there are certain algorithms that take into account edge cases where the outcome can be made more robust (by doing operations in a certain order or noticing when features are very close, IIRC). A simple grep for e.g. `robust` might show you some in-roads there:

> policies/robustness/robust_point_type.hpp:`// Meta-function to typedef a robust point type for a poli`
>
> algorithms/detail/overlay/get_turn_info_helpers.hpp:    `// Used ranges - owned by get_turns or (for`
>
> algorithms/detail/overlay/get_turn_info_helpers.hpp:`// Version with rescaling, having robust points`
>
> algorithms/detail/overlay/append_no_dups_or_spikes.hpp:    `// Try using specified robust policy`

I'm merely grazing the surface here, I don't claim to understand much of what is being noted there.

### Using arbitrary precision or decimals

Precision is one dimension, source-fidelity when the input is in decimal form is another. Short of going to MPFR/GMP/ttmath (as mentioned) you can easily drop in Boost Multiprecision. This gives you fast proof-of-concept since it ships with boost, and also allows you to switch to GMP or MPFR backends transparently.

See also:

- [Boost Geometry and exact point types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532776/boost-geometry-and-exact-point-types/25537371#25537371)
- [How to use Boost::Geometry _union with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637066/how-to-use-boostgeometry-union-with-integers/45654293#45654293)
- [Boost geometry intersection does not output correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27335345/boost-geometry-intersection-does-not-output-correctly/27369064#27369064)

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f8309cb2ade10b8)**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;
namespace bg = boost::geometry;

//// Note, cpp_dec_float<0> is variable-precision!
// using Number = mp::number<mp::cpp_dec_float<0>, mp::et_off>;

// Fixed precision, avoids allocating and populates std::numeric_limits<>
// with concrete data
using Number = mp::number<mp::cpp_dec_float<50>, mp::et_off>;

using point = boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<Number>;
using polygon = bg::model::polygon<point, false>;

polygon create_poly(std::vector<std::tuple<Number, Number>> pts) {
    polygon poly;
    for (const auto& [x, y] : pts)
        bg::append(poly, bg::make<point>(x, y));
    auto [x_1, y_1] = pts[0];
    bg::append(poly, bg::make<point>(x_1, y_1));
    return poly;
}

bool perform_simple_union(const polygon& p1, const polygon& p2) {
    std::vector<polygon> output; 
    bg::union_(p1, p2, output);
    return output.size() == 1;
}

Number find_epsilon(Number left, Number right) {

    Number eps = (left + right) / 2;
    if (right - left < std::numeric_limits<Number>::epsilon())
        return left;

    polygon a = create_poly(
        std::vector<std::tuple<Number, Number>>{
            {1.0, 1.0}, { 2.0,1.0 }, { 2.0, 2.0 }, { 1.0,2.0 }
        }
    );

    polygon b = create_poly(
        std::vector<std::tuple<Number, Number>>{
            {2.0 + eps, 1.0}, { 3.0 + eps, 1.0 }, { 3.0 + eps, 2.0 }, { 2.0 + eps,2.0 }
        }
    );

    if ( perform_simple_union(a, b) ) {
        return find_epsilon(eps, right);
    } else {
        return find_epsilon(left, eps);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "nextafter(0, 1):  " << nextafter(Number(0), Number(1)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Number: eps()     " << std::numeric_limits<Number>::epsilon()      << "\n";
    std::cout << "Number: min_exp() " << std::numeric_limits<Number>::min_exponent10 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Number: max_exp() " << std::numeric_limits<Number>::max_exponent10 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Number: min()     " << std::numeric_limits<Number>::min()          << "\n";
    std::cout << "Number: max()     " << std::numeric_limits<Number>::max()          << "\n";

    auto eps = find_epsilon(0.0, 1.0);

    std::cout << std::setprecision(180);
    std::cout << "eps == " << eps << "\n";

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "zero? " << (eps == 0) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
nextafter(0, 1):  1e-67108864
Number: eps()     1e-49
Number: min_exp() -67108864
Number: max_exp() 67108864
Number: min()     1e-67108864
Number: max()     1e+67108864
eps == 0
zero? true
```

For `cpp_dec_float<0>` it prints (note the "weird" numeric_limits<>::eps` in the variable-precision situation):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60011b28b13e3e6e)**

```
nextafter(0, 1):  1e-67108864
Number: eps()     1e-08
Number: min_exp() -67108864
Number: max_exp() 67108864
Number: min()     1e-67108864
Number: max()     1e+67108864
eps == 0
zero? true
```

Comment: this is interesting. So the fact that the double precision case appears to use an epsilon-based definition of equality is not on purpose but is an artifact of double precision just not being precise enough? I was actually already planning on using boost::multiprecision numbers in the application I am working on just havent decided on which particular one.

Comment: I think it's still epsilon based. Just with a much farther "horizon". It's not _explicitly_ epsilon "oriented" (they'd have documented this), but in practice comparisons will get inaccurate around the epsilon value.

Comment: Just an experiment to illustrate how "epsilon" varies with magnitudes: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/589064b79a6e1ca4